# S3 backend: can't overwrite AWS_S3_ENDPOINT

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I want to use an S3 backend to remotely store my tfstate.

Since I want to use a bucket on Wasabi, and not AWS, I set the endpoint to `s3.wasabisys.com`.

However, terraform still tries to use AWS.

I tried to use the `TF_AWS_S3_ENDPOINT` environment variable, but even hardcoded values don't work:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket   = "my-bucket"
    key      = "my-key"
    region   = "us-east-1"
    endpoint = "s3.wasabisys.com"
    access_key = "xxxx"
    secret_key = "xxxx"
  }
}
```

Output:

```
stanislas@mbp ~> terraform init
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.11.10
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [INFO] Go runtime version: go1.11.1
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"/usr/local/Cellar/terraform/0.11.10/bin/terraform", "init"}
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /Users/stanislas/.terraformrc
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [INFO] CLI command args: []string{"init"}
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [DEBUG] command: loading backend config file: /Users/stanislas/git/xxx
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [DEBUG] command: no data state file found for backend config

Initializing the backend...
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "be941477-7111-2a13-ceed-55e4fba0bcbd"
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [INFO] Building AWS region structure
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [INFO] Building AWS auth structure
2018/10/25 08:53:35 [INFO] Setting AWS metadata API timeout to 100ms
2018/10/25 08:53:36 [INFO] Ignoring AWS metadata API endpoint at default location as it doesn't return any instance-id
2018/10/25 08:53:36 [INFO] AWS Auth provider used: "StaticProvider"
2018/10/25 08:53:36 [INFO] Initializing DeviceFarm SDK connection
2018/10/25 08:53:36 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request sts/GetCallerIdentity Details:
---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: sts.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.14.31 (go1.11.1; darwin; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.11.10
Content-Length: 43
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxx, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=xxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
X-Amz-Date: 20181025T065336Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip

Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15
-----------------------------------------------------
2018/10/25 08:53:36 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response sts/GetCallerIdentity Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Connection: close
Content-Length: 306
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Thu, 25 Oct 2018 06:53:36 GMT
X-Amzn-Requestid: xxx

-----------------------------------------------------
2018/10/25 08:53:36 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code>
    <Message>The security token included in the request is invalid.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>xxx</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
2018/10/25 08:53:36 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate Response sts/GetCallerIdentity failed, not retrying, error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
  status code: 403, request id: xxx
2018/10/25 08:53:36 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
Error configuring the backend "s3": InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
  status code: 403, request id: xxx

Please update the configuration in your Terraform files to fix this error
then run this command again.
```

As you can see, Terraform sends a request to `sts.amazonaws.com`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the set the following options to `true` ?

- `skip_requesting_account_id`
- `skip_credentials_validation`
- `skip_get_ec2_platforms`
- `skip_metadata_api_check`

As those seems to be needed when not using AWS (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/15553#issuecomment-383294678).